# How do I do arithmetic on attributes from two different tables in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I apologize if this a simple and redundant question, but I just can't seem to find anything that matches what I'm looking for after several hours of googling. I'm very new to R.

My goal is to find what percentage of Delta Airline flights arrive late depending on which airport they depart from. Here is my code so far:

```
#install.packages("nycflights13")
#library(nycflights13)
flts <- nycflights13::flights

# filtering by Delta Airlines and late arrival dates
all_delta_flights <- filter(flts, carrier == "DL")
all_late_delta_flights <- filter(flts, carrier == "DL", arr_delay > 0)

# group by departing airport
by_origin <- all_delta_flights %>% group_by(origin)
by_origin_late <- all_late_delta_flights %>% group_by(origin) 

# get number of flights by departure airport
by_origin_late %>% summarise(n = n())
by_origin %>% summarise(n = n())
```

The last two lines of code output the following two tables.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  <chr>  <int>
1 EWR     1725
2 JFK     6353
3 LGA     8335

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  origin     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 EWR     4342
2 JFK    20701
3 LGA    23067
```

What I want to do now is create a new table combining the n column such as

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  origin     n
  <chr>  <double>
1 EWR     .397     #  == 1725 / 4342
2 JFK     ???      #  == 6353 / 20701
3 LGA     ???
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Thank you!

Comment: `left_join(tbl1, tbl2, by="origin") %>% mutate(ratio=n.x/n.y)` (you could also rename the `n`s first)

Comment: That sounds like that would work. Let me try that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single pipe without joining:

```
flts %>% 
    filter(carrier == "DL") %>% 
    group_by(origin) %>% 
    summarize(percent = sum(arr_delay > 0) / n())
```

---

Seems the `arr_delay` column contains NA values, you might need to add `na.rm=T` in `sum`:

```
flts %>% 
    filter(carrier == "DL") %>% 
    group_by(origin) %>% 
    summarize(percent = sum(arr_delay > 0, na.rm=T) / n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  origin percent
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 EWR      0.397
#2 JFK      0.307
#3 LGA      0.361
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a much cleaner answer than what I was going to implement!

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why did the first response return NA for all `percent` values? Can a single NA value can ruin the whole `sum` calculation?

Comment: Yes. `sum` returns NA if there is any NA values in the vector. For your case, it's possible that for each `origin`, there is at least one NA value in the `arr_delay` column.